# Get number of bills from range of dollar amounts - cascading larger to smaller bills

Tags: excel, integer, excel-formula, rounding, worksheet-function

I am building an envelope system where I withdraw a number of bills each pay period and put them into envelopes. What I am trying to do is to determine via formula how many bills of each I need to have. Here is an example:-

My funds would be:

```
Kids      $ 10
Car       $ 50
Gas       $100
Groceries $225
Gifts     $ 40
---------------
Total:    $425
```

What I want is a base formula to extract the number of bills of each of: $1, $5, $10, $20 and $50

How to extract numbers of $50s from this list which should give me 7 [1 Car, 2 Gas, 4 Groceries]?

Ultimate goal should be this:

```
0  $ 1 bills    $  0
1  $ 5 bills    $  5
1  $10 bills    $ 10
3  $20 bills    $ 60
7  $50 bills    $350
--------------------
Total Cash:     $425
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but couldn't you try something like =ROUNDDOWN("Expense","Bill_Value")?  That way you would get 7 bills as you required.  Similarly if you were to look for the number of $10 bills you could let "Bill_Value" = $10

Comment: I'm not rounding, I'm trying to determine how many number of occurrences are in range

Comment: You're right, my formula isn't sufficient.  Let me make sure I understand correctly, since there are 29 ways to make a dollar with quarters, dimes, and nickels, and similarlly there are many ways to get $50, $100, $225 with $50, $20, $10... dollar bills.  Is the idea to prioritize larger bills over smaller bills (i.e. minimize the number of bills)?

Comment: Yes, larger bills then cascade down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNTESTED. With `Kids` in A2 and 50,20,10,5,1 in C1:G1 then perhaps in C2 and copied across and down:

```
=INT(MIN($B2,$B2-SUMPRODUCT($B$1:B$1*$B2:B2))/C$1)
```

The results might then be summed by column (excluding the labels) to get the count by denomination and each sum multiplied by the column labels (eg `=SUM(C2:C10)*C$1`) then the sums summed as a cross-check on the total.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is in range `A2:B6`, I would use some auxiliary cells on its right, like this:

```
|    A    |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  |
                  50    20    10     5     1
Kids         10    0     0     1     0     0
Car          50    1     0     0     0     0
Gas         100    2     0     0     0     0
Groceries   225    4     1     0     1     0
Gifts        40    0     2     0     0     0
```

These are the formulas in row 2:

```
C2: =ROUNDDOWN(B2/C$1,0)
D2: =ROUNDDOWN((B2-C2*C$1)/D$1,0)
E2: =ROUNDDOWN((B2-C2*C$1-D2*D$1)/E$1,0)
F2: =ROUNDDOWN((B2-C2*C$1-D2*D$1-E2*E$1)/F$1,0)
G2: =ROUNDDOWN((B2-C2*C$1-D2*D$1-E2*E$1-F2*F$1)/G$1,0)
```

*These formulas could be a bit simpler if you use more auxiliary columns with intermediate results.*

Then just copy them to the rows below. Finally, you get the results using a simple `SUM` per auxiliary bill column, placing them as you like and multiplying those results by the bill value in another column.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to implement the following algorithm:

As in your example we have `(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(10,50,100,225,40)` as our set of values.  For each value run `=ROUNDDOWN(a/50,0)`,`=ROUNDDOWN(b/50,0)`, and so on in a column adjacent to your column of values.

Next, multiply these values by the divisor (in this case 50) and subtract this from the initial amount.

Now run this again in a loop for 10, 5, and 1.  That is, run this over the array of divisors (50,10,5,1).  You will need three columns for each divisor value, one for the initial use of =ROUNDDOWN(), one for the multiplication, and one for the subtraction.  In total then you'll need 12 columns of information.

There is probably a way to implement this in VBA that will cut it down to the three columns of counts you need for each bill type with ease.

Comment: @Demodave Definitely, Andrew's answer is a more concise way of doing what I've done.  There's probably an even more elegant way somewhere.